# How to be able to delete right-aligned text from the left side?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following inputs side-by-side that are supposed to be time inputs stylized as single input:

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

input {
  min-width: 0;
  border: none;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#hours {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <input type="text" id="hours" maxlength=2>
  <div id="colon"><span>:</span></div>
  <input type="text" id="minutes" maxlength=2>
</div>
```

For the hours input, I right-align the text so that it will type the values close to the colon.

But, when I want to edit the value of it, it feels more natural to place the cursor on the left side. However when using the delete key, it won't delete because it expects the cursor to be on the right side.

How can I make the delete button delete the values also from the left side?

The desired behavior is that it still deletes the lowest digit first, i.e. if the input there is 12, and delete is clicked, it should delete 2 first

Update: This is what I want, which I manage to do using `dir="rtl"` on the hours div:

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

input {
  min-width: 0;
  border: none;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#hours {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <input type="text" id="hours" maxlength=2 dir="rtl">
  <div id="colon"><span>:</span></div>
  <input type="text" id="minutes" maxlength=2>
</div>
```

But could it be done better?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you can use JS to handle the "delete" `keypress` event in the input element and program the required functionality.

```js
document.getElementById('hours').addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
  if (event.key === 'Delete') {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.value = this.value.slice(0, -1);
  }
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

input {
  min-width: 0;
  border: none;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#hours {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <input type="text" id="hours" maxlength=2>
  <div id="colon"><span>:</span></div>
  <input type="text" id="minutes" maxlength=2>
</div>
```